# zh-CN xx.resource.dll for localization is not generated when build web app in Linux server

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, build, localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been localizing the our .Net Core (2.1) MVC Project with Resource files and **CookiesCultureRequest**. We have 3  additional languages now such as korean, Japnees and Chines.

The issue is when build and publish the solution in the Linux deployment server. only **zh-CN** folder and resource.dll has not been generated. But in my local Windows machine does all. both machine/VM has the same LOCALE LANGUAGE (C.UTF-8)

What should i do for forcing to generate the dll when build the solution?

Thanks

Comment: `The issue is when build and publish the solution in the Linux deployment server.` Can you clarify more about how you build and publish in your Linux deployment server?

Comment: @FeiHan , I am executing only `dotnet build` command to build the solution in the Linux server.